# ActiveRecord::Relation print specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord::Relation between:

**Order class:**

`has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"` and

**OrderTransaction class:**

```
belongs_to :order    
serialize :params
```

> ActiveRecord::Relation [#OrderTransaction id: 5, order_id: 11, action: "purchase", amount: 26044, success: true, authorization: "8V863650823585301", message: "Success", params: {"timestamp"=>"2015-10-16T23:11:09Z", "ack"=>"Success", "correlation_id"=>"9b5eb7051dbe3", "version"=>"72", "build"=>"18308778", "amount"=>"260.44", "amount_currency_id"=>"USD", "avs_code"=>"X", "cvv2_code"=>"M", "transaction_id"=>"8V863650823585301", "Timestamp"=>"2015-10-16T23:11:09Z", "Ack"=>"Success", "CorrelationID"=>"9b5eb7051dbe3", "Version"=>"72", "Build"=>"18308778", "Amount"=>"260.44", "AVSCode"=>"X", "CVV2Code"=>"M", "TransactionID"=>"8V863650823585301"}, created_at: "2015-10-16 23:11:09", updated_at: "2015-10-16 23:11:09"]

I'm trying to print in irb console the params[:transaction_id] but i cannot find the right way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
OrderTransaction.where(message: "Success").map { |p| p['params']['transaction_id'] }
```

To get only one `transaction_id`:

```
x = OrderTransaction.where(message: "Success").last
x['params']['transaction_id']
```

Comment: Lets suppose that i have define all the ActiveRecord::Relation to a variable named x. How can i express it?

Comment: you mean, `x = params` then you can do: `x.map { |p| p['transaction_id'] }` this will give you all the `transaction_id`s. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: I'm getting this error:  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'params' for #<OrderTransaction::ActiveRecord_Relation`

Comment: how do you get the `OrderTransaction::ActiveRecord_Relation`, can you that code?

Comment: I find the relation through `x = OrderTransaction.where(message: "Success").last`

Comment: do: `x = OrderTransaction.where(message: "Success")` without `.last`. that should give you a `ActiveRecord_Relation `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92888/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-gregory-ynwa).